# Account linking in Google Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, account-linking

I've tried many times to deploy my Google Assistant project. But it's rejected for the following reason:

> Your Action's content could not be accessed due to account restrictions or a paywall. If your Actions require account linking, please add instructions on how to trigger your account linking prompt in the "Testing Instructions” field of the developer console before submitting your Action again. In this case, you indicated in the AoG console that your Action has account linking using Google Sign-In but during testing we weren't able to find an account linking prompt. If your Action does not have account linking, then kindly clear the data in the "Account Linking" section of the AoG console.

I have no idea how to fix this. The project doesn't contain account linking, but I don't know how to clear the data as suggested.

I've searched the entire internet, but couldn't find it.

Comment: It seems like your project doesn't contain account linking but maybe it should? What is your Dialogflow project doing? It seems like it's not providing the review team with the right expectations.

Answer (score 2):

In your actions on google console you can find the accountlinking settings under **Develop > Account linking**. In these setting there should be a slider which you can turn off to disable account linking for you project.

[image]